# How to implement this JSFiddle code to my page?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, jsfiddle

This is probably a very newbie question but I'm trying to copy (not embed) code from the following Highcharts JSFiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/3cr2yebq/9/

My page is a basic HTML5 page. I've copied the html-code from the top as well as put the Javascript to my page inside  tags. It doesn't seem to work at all. Even tried it in an empty HTML-page and it didn't work.

When I checked my page with a debugger, I got these errors:

**highcharts.js:309**
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined

**highcharts-more.js:8**
Uncaught TypeError: l.getOptions is not a function

**solid-gauge.js:9**
Uncaught TypeError: a.getOptions is not a function

**gauge.php:10** 
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

HTML from the fiddle:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
<div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
<div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
<div id="container-rpm" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
$(function () {

var gaugeOptions = {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge'
    },

    title: null,

    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#FFF',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#8dc63f'], // green
            [0.5, '#8dc63f'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#8dc63f'] // red
            ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickPixelInterval: 400,
        tickWidth: 0,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: 5,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    }
};

// The speed gauge
$('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: {
            text: 'Press'
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Press',
        data: [83],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' + ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || '#151515') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">%</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

}));

// The RPM gauge
$('#container-rpm').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: {
            text: 'Youtube'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Youtube',
        data: [83],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' + ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || '#151515') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">%</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
        }
    }]

}));

});
```

Thanks in advance for taking your time to look at the issue!

Comment: need to include all resources including jQuery.js ...order is important

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I was using  too old version of jQuery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you imported JQuery into your site? It looks as though the code needs it. You can add it by putting this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Onto your site. Hope that helps.

Comment: @jfriend00 my bad, deleted the comment. Donutttt I'd suggest you add your comment to your answer.

Comment: You're right I don't - but I did also link to the wrong cdn :P

Comment: I'm fairly new, sorry, could you explain what you mean?

Comment: Instead of adding the "To be clear[...]" part in the comments section, you should edit you answer and paste it in to the actual answer.

Comment: Thanks! I had JQuery 1.8. which apparently didn't work. The one you provided fixed the problem. Thank you so much!